# Difference between hasOwnProperty and if (a[b][c]) in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Both of the following examples seem to work. I was just wondering what the difference is and how comes both of them work?

```
if (a[b].hasOwnProperty(c)) {return "Works";}

if (a[b][c]) {return "Works";}
```

However, the following for some reason seems to cause a lot of issues, although it seems like it should work:

```
if (typeof(a[b][c]) !== undefined) {return "Works";}
```

I'm just not understanding quite what's wrong.

Many thanks, I'm just starting out so it's probably something easy.

Comment: what result do you expect for that conditional statement ?

Comment: Which one @mpm? I just wanted to basically check that a[b][c] exists as something, and was wondering what the differences between these three methods were.

Turns out the third one is poor syntax, the first two have slightly different use cases. Thanks everyone, so helpful!

Comment: you want to test if b has a property c?

Comment: Basically yeah. If it exists in some form or another.

Comment: OK, see my answer edit then

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`typeof x` can never be `undefined`; it will always be a string. That string can be `"undefined"` though, but that's not `undefined`.

There are differences between `a[b].hasOwnProperty(c)` and `a[b][c]` though:

- `a[b][c]` will be `false` if the value exists but is a [falsy one (`false`, `0`, `""`, `NaN`, `null`, `undefined`)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy).
- `hasOwnProperty` only looks at properties within the object itself, not up the prototype chain. (However, it will return `true` even for falsy values.)

Answer (score 2):

[`typeof` operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof) returns a string and the check should works with a string.

BTW, it is not a function, it is an operator which works without parentheses.

```
if (typeof a[b][c] !== 'undefined') {
    return "Works";
}
```

You could check with [`in` operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/in).

```
if (c in a[b]) {
    return "Works";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Well some properties can be defined on an object prototype, while others on the object itself.

```
function O(){ this.bar = "bar" }

O.prototype.foo = "foo"

var o = new O

Object.hasOwnProperty(o,'foo') // false 
Object.hasOwnProperty(o,'bar') // true
```

yet

```
console.log(o.foo) // displays 'foo'
```

Your snippet

```
if (a[b][c]) {return "Works";}
```

tests what javascript considers "truthy" values. If the property c doesn't exist on b then that test is evaluated to false

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy

To test if a property is defined in some form then use

```
if(typeof a.b !== 'undefined'){ console.log('a has a property named b') }
```

note: it's "undefined" as a string, not undefined .